# WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask example

Tags: background, task, watchkit, watchconnectivity, watchos-3

I want to pass data from my iOS App to my watchOS 3 app using WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask

How do I set up code in my watchOS App to handle the data being transferred?

For example in the past I used this iOS code to send a message from the iOS App and if there was no connection send a context:

```
func sendTable()
{
    let tableInfo: WatchWorkout = PhoneData().buildWatchTableData(Foundation.Date().refDays())
    let archivedTable: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tableInfo)
    if validSession
    {
        sendMessage([Keys.UpdateType : PhoneUpdateType.TableInfo.rawValue, Keys.Workout: archivedTable])
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            try updateApplicationContext([Keys.UpdateType : PhoneUpdateType.TableInfo.rawValue, Keys.Workout: archivedTable])
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Phone Session - error sending info: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


func sendMessage(_ message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: (([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)? = nil, errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)? = nil)
{
    print("Phone Session - phone sent message")
    session!.sendMessage(message,
        replyHandler:
        nil,
        errorHandler:
        {
            (error) -> Void in
            print("Phone Session - Error Message during transfer to Watch: \(error)")
        }
    )
}


func updateApplicationContext(_ applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) throws
{
    print("Phone Session - phone sent context")
    if ((session) != nil)
    {
        do
        {
            try session!.updateApplicationContext(applicationContext)
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print("Phone Session - OPPS something wrong - context send failed")
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to code the receipt of this data as a background task on the watch.

Can someone provide some example code or post a link? The only Apple example code is not very helpful:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/WatchBackgroundRefresh/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Quick Switch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/QuickSwitch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016647) sample code was updated together with the release of watchOS 3 to include an example of handling the WatchConnectivity background refresh task.

Comment: I have a similar problem, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537027/wkwatchconnectivityrefreshbackgroundtask-is-never-triggered-in-background-but-w). Apparently `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask`is never called, not even in the demo project QuickSwitch.

Comment: I submitted the problem to Apple Developer Technical Support, and they confirmed (# 652471299) the problem in watchOS 3, and suggested to file a bug report, what I did (# 29284559). However, I must say, I don't have much hope that this will help soon. My previous bug reports have usually been treated months later, if at all...

Comment: Was there any update on this bug? Having some issues myself

Answer (score 1):

@ccjensen The Quick Switch sample code doesn't work, is it? 
It will crash on my iPhone6 iOS10.0 beta3. I sent feedback already last Friday.

In my Case, calling 
`updateApplicationContext(_:)`
`transferUserInfo(_:)`
`transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(_:)`
`transferFile(_:metadata:)`
on iPhone side never trigger `handle(_:)` listener.

Comment: Can't comment, so write answer

Comment: probably best to file a radar and make sure to attach the crash report!