# WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask competing with WCSessionDelegate

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to adapt my code from using only `WCSessionDelegate` callbacks in the foreground to accepting `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` via `handleBackgroundTasks:` in the background. The documentation states that background tasks may come in asynchronously and that one should not call `setTaskCompleted` until the `WCSession`'s `hasContentPending` is `NO`.

If I put my watch app into the background and `transferUserInfo:` from an iPhone app, I am able to successfully receive my first `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask`. However, `hasContentPending` is always `YES`, so I save away the task and simply return from my `WCSessionDelegate` method. If I `transferUserInfo:` again, `hasContentPending` is `NO`, but there is no `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` associated with this message. That is, subsequent `transferUserInfo:` do not trigger a call to `handleBackgroundTask:` –- they're simply handled by the `WCSessionDelegate`. Even if I immediately `setTaskCompleted` without checking `hasContentPending`, subsequent `transferUserInfo:` are handled by `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` without me needing to activate a `WCSession` again.

I'm not sure what to do here. There doesn't seem to be a way to force a `WCSession` to deactivate, and following the documentation about delaying `setTaskCompleted` seems to be getting me into trouble with the OS.

I've posted and documented a sample project illustrating my workflow on [GitHub](https://github.com/gfiumara/BackgroundWatchConnectivity), pasting my `WKExtensionDelegate` code below. Am I making an incorrect choice or interpreting the documentation incorrectly somewhere along the line?

I've looked at the [QuickSwitch 2.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/QuickSwitch/Introduction/Intro.html) source code (after fixing the Swift 3 bugs, rdar://28503030), and their method simply doesn't seem to work (there's [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535025/wkwatchconnectivityrefreshbackgroundtask-example) about this). I've tried using KVO for `WCSession`'s `hasContentPending` and `activationState`, but there's still never any `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` to complete, which makes sense to be given my current explanation of the issue.

```
#import "ExtensionDelegate.h"

@interface ExtensionDelegate()

@property (nonatomic, strong) WCSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask *> *watchConnectivityTasks;

@end

@implementation ExtensionDelegate

#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)handleBackgroundTasks:(NSSet<WKRefreshBackgroundTask *> *)backgroundTasks
{
    NSLog(@"Watch app woke up for background task");

    for (WKRefreshBackgroundTask *task in backgroundTasks) {
        if ([task isKindOfClass:[WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask class]]) {
            [self handleBackgroundWatchConnectivityTask:(WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask *)task];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Handling an unsupported type of background task");
            [task setTaskCompleted];
        }
    }
}

- (void)handleBackgroundWatchConnectivityTask:(WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask *)task
{
    NSLog(@"Handling WatchConnectivity background task");

    if (self.watchConnectivityTasks == nil)
        self.watchConnectivityTasks = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self.watchConnectivityTasks addObject:task];

    if (self.session.activationState != WCSessionActivationStateActivated)
        [self.session activateSession];
}

#pragma mark - Properties

- (WCSession *)session
{
    NSAssert([WCSession isSupported], @"WatchConnectivity is not supported");

    if (_session != nil)
        return (_session);

    _session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    _session.delegate = self;

    return (_session);
}

#pragma mark - WCSessionDelegate

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session activationDidCompleteWithState:(WCSessionActivationState)activationState error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch(activationState) {
        case WCSessionActivationStateActivated:
            NSLog(@"WatchConnectivity session activation changed to \"activated\"");
            break;
        case WCSessionActivationStateInactive:
            NSLog(@"WatchConnectivity session activation changed to \"inactive\"");
            break;
        case WCSessionActivationStateNotActivated:
            NSLog(@"WatchConnectivity session activation changed to \"NOT activated\"");
            break;
    }
}

- (void)sessionWatchStateDidChange:(WCSession *)session
{
    switch(session.activationState) {
        case WCSessionActivationStateActivated:
            NSLog(@"WatchConnectivity session activation changed to \"activated\"");
            break;
        case WCSessionActivationStateInactive:
            NSLog(@"WatchConnectivity session activation changed to \"inactive\"");
            break;
        case WCSessionActivationStateNotActivated:
            NSLog(@"WatchConnectivity session activation changed to \"NOT activated\"");
            break;
    }
}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)userInfo
{
    /*
     * NOTE:
     * Even if this method only sets the task to be completed, the default
     * WatchConnectivity session delegate still picks up the message
     * without another call to handleBackgroundTasks:
     */

    NSLog(@"Received message with counter value = %@", userInfo[@"counter"]);

    if (session.hasContentPending) {
        NSLog(@"Task not completed. More content pending...");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No pending content. Marking all tasks (%ld tasks) as complete.", (unsigned long)self.watchConnectivityTasks.count);
        for (WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask *task in self.watchConnectivityTasks)
            [task setTaskCompleted];
        [self.watchConnectivityTasks removeAllObjects];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and my understanding it sounds like this is working correctly.

The way this was explained to me is that the new `handleBackgroundTasks:` on watchOS is intended to be a way for:

- the system to communicate to the WatchKit extension why it is being launched/resumed in the background, and
- a way for the WatchKit extension to let the system know when it has completed the work it wants to do and can therefore be terminated/suspended again.

This means that whenever an incoming WatchConnectivity payload is received on the Watch and your WatchKit extension is terminated or suspended you should expect one `handleBackgroundTasks:` callback letting you know why you are running in the background. This means you could receive 1 `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` but several WatchConnectivity callbacks (files, userInfos, applicationContext). The `hasContentPending` lets you know when your `WCSession` has delivered all of the initial, pending content (files, userInfos, applicationContext). At that point, you should call the setTaskCompleted on the `WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask` object.

Then you can expect that your WatchKit extension will soon thereafter be suspended or terminated unless you have received other `handleBackgroundTasks:` callbacks and therefore have other WK background task objects to complete.

I have found that when attaching to the processes with a debugger that OSs might not suspended them like they normally would, so it'd suggest inspecting the behavior here using logging if you want to be sure to avoid any of those kind of issues.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I admittedly have only been testing in the simulator attached to the debugger, so I can believe this. If this is true, then KVO sounds like the correct move (save away any `BackgroundTask`s, and clear them when `hasContentPending` observer is triggered to `NO`). Let me do a bit more testing before I come back to mark as answered.

Comment: Yea, I've found the simulators to be even less accurate to expected behavior than on device with debugger attached. I've found in the simulators that once a process is running it never suspends again, so that matches what you were describing.